# Print to out file

Tags: bash, perl

I am trying to find intersecting lines between two files. One of the files is 'Sample_hg19_mapped.bed' and the other one 'intersect.RData' has some of the same data as the first one.

Bed file:

```
chrM    16338   16363   HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:1112:17158:21371  255 -
chrM    16352   16377   HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:1102:7906:41988   255 -
chrM    16352   16377   HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:2113:18341:36393  255 -
chrM    16376   16401   HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:1310:14517:85268  255 -
```

RData file:

```
HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:1310:14517:85268
HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:2113:18341:36393
HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:2113:45341:56393
```

And as an output, it needs to give the line of BED file which has the same value in the RData.file. For example, the first and the second value of RData exists in BED file,but not the third one, so in output it needs to be :

```
chrM    16376   16401   HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:1310:14517:85268  255 -
chrM    16352   16377   HWI-ST575:220:C2MMMACXX:3:2113:18341:36393  255 -
```

I managed it with those code :

```
perl -ane '$f=$F[0].$F[1]; print "$k{$f}$_" if $k{$f}; $k{$f}=$_;' Sample_hg19_mapped.bed  intersect.RData
```

But those lines that match are on the screen and I want them to keep in the file but I cannot make the output file. I tried this one by changing a lot:

```
####!/bin/bash     
perl -ane '$f=$F[0].$F[1]';"Sample_hg19_mapped.bed intersect.RData"

if $k{$f};$k{$f}=$_ {
       print "$k{$f}$_";
} else {
       print "epic fail";
}
open($f, ">", "output.txt")
       or die "cannot open > output.txt: $!"; 
close $f;

print "done\n";
```

But I have so many errors like:

```
/var/spool/slurmd/job2572366/slurm_script: line 3: Sample_hg19_mapped.bed intersect.RData: command not found
/var/spool/slurmd/job2572366/slurm_script: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/var/spool/slurmd/job2572366/slurm_script: line 6: `} else {'
```

Can you maybe help me on this?
Thank you so much

Comment: Go easy on yourself @podeeng. For someone who is asking a question for the first time, you have done a great job so +1 for that.

Comment: Thank you for the motivation!^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your command works but outputs to the screen, simply redirect that to a file:

```
command > output.txt
```

e.g.

```
perl -ane '$f=$F[0].$F[1]; print "$k{$f}$_" if $k{$f}; $k{$f}=$_;' Sample_hg19_mapped.bed  intersect.RData > output.txt
```

If you want to remove all the empty lines you can add `next if /^\s*$/;` to the start:

```
perl -ane 'next if /^\s*$/; $f=$F[0].$F[1]; print "$k{$f}$_" if $k{$f}; $k{$f}=$_;' Sample_hg19_mapped.bed  intersect.RData > output.txt
```

This will skip any input lines which are only whitespace.

Comment: @podeeng what happens when you try it? Running this from the command line creates the file for me.

Comment: it creates a file but it is missing.. It gives output to "head output.txt" but not "tail output.bed". It blocks me to check it and thats why I couldnt use it ..

Comment: You mean `tail output.txt` ?

Comment: When i try with next if /^\s*$/; i can see the tail also! So, it worked! YAY! Thank you so much!

Comment: @podeeng Great! Don't forget to accept an answer if the problem is resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is abit messy and the erros are from there although if you want to output to a file you can do this:

```
 open (MYFILE, '>>NameOfFile');
 print MYFILE $variable
```

Comment: So, i should do : perl -ane '$f=$F[0].$F[1]';"Sample_hg19_mapped.bed intersect.RData"

if $k{$f};$k{$f}=$_ {
       print "$k{$f}$_";
} else {
       print "epic fail";
}
open(MYFILE,">>output.txt")
       or die "cannot open > output.txt: $!"; print MYFILE
close $f;

print "done\n";

Comment: Not nesesarry. You open the file on top of the script ( open (MYFILE, '>>NameOfFile'); And when you want to print inside the file instead the command line you just do " print MYFILE *what you want to print* instead of "print *what you want to print*"

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this:

This uses your RData vales as hash keys, and then looks for them in the bed file, printing any matches to 'output.txt'.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $bed, '<', 'in.txt';

open my $rdata, '<', 'Rdata.txt';

my (%bed, %rdata);

while(<$rdata>){
    chomp;
    $rdata{$_} = 2; # Each line is a key in the hash %rdata
}

open my $out_file, '>', 'output.txt';

while(<$bed>){
    chomp;
    next unless /chrM/;
    my @split = split/\t/;
    print $out_file "$_\n" if $rdata{$split[3]}; # will print to output.txt any line where the 4th column matches a key from %rdata 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. But i couldnt find the part that BED file in your script because I have so many BED files in my directory, how can make it specific?

Comment: `open my $file, '<', 'whatever_your_file_is_called.bed';`

Comment: Ofcourse..I tried your script and it gave so many errors that i dont understand why.. --> /var/spool/slurmd/job2573679/slurm_script: line 3: use: command not found
/var/spool/slurmd/job2573679/slurm_script: line 4: use: command not found
/var/spool/slurmd/job2573679/slurm_script: line 5: use: command not found
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
/var/spool/slurmd/job2573679/slurm_script: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `%bed,'
/var/spool/slurmd/job2573679/slurm_script: line 11: `my (%bed, %rdata);'

Comment: What do you have at the top of your script? it should be `#!/usr/bin/perl
`

Comment: oy! it was #!/bin/bash. I will change it

Comment: Another type of error occured--> slurmstepd: execve(): bad interpreter(usr/bin/perl): No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The following `perl` one-liner should do what you need:

```
perl -lane'
    BEGIN { $x = pop; %h = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <>; @ARGV = $x } 
    print if /./ && $h{$F[3]}
' intersect.RData Sample_hg19_mapped.bed
```

- We load the intersect.RData in a hash map in the `BEGIN` block
- In the main body we check if the third field from Sample_hg19_mapped.bed file is present in our hash map. If it does then print the line.
- If the output looks fine to you then you can redirect to another file.

Comment: @podeeng Sure, if you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I am still waiting for the code to be finished, i hope that it will work! (looks good as yet) I will!